# Multiple image resize using php at once

Tags: php

I am using PHP GD2 to resize and crop image using below function

```
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

But I want to create many samples of a single image of different sizes. I am currently repeating same function in single file to get different sizes. But is there any way, perhaps using array or something using which I can achieve the same result?

Comment: A loop with different data?

Comment: What does [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) say? Can it take an array of sizes and output an array of images? No? Well, then. No.